# Swift FCM send notification to specific token Not Working at Background

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I working now on the notification system for my app.
I used This func to send Notification to specific token device:

```
func sendPushNotification(to token: String, title: String, body: String) {
        let urlString = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        let paramString: [String : Any] = ["to" : token,
                                           "content-available": 1,
                                           "priority":"high",
                                           "notification" : ["title" : title, "body" : body],
                                           "data" : ["user" : "test_id"]
        ]
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:paramString, options: [.prettyPrinted])
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("key=My Key", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)  { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let jsonData = data {
                    if let jsonDataDict  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        NSLog("Received data:\n\(jsonDataDict))")
                    }
                }
            } catch let err as NSError {
                print("Error Notification: \(err.debugDescription)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

I got the notification like I expected but when the app at background I get the Notification alert but 'didReceiveRemoteNotification' not called even when I added ' "content-available": 1 ' to my Notification params.

[My Capability Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3knL.png)

AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
```

import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

```
var userDeviceToken = ""
var userModel: UserModel?
var userID = ""

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    // check if have user
    self.userModel = KeychainUserModel.shared.retrive(key: .user)
    if let userID = self.userModel?.userID {
        self.userID = userID
        KeychainModel.shared.saveString(value: userID, key: .userID)
    }
    
    
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { sccsess, _ in
        guard sccsess else {
            return
        }
        
        print("Success in APNS Registry")
    }
    
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    
    return true
}


// MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
    return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    // Called when the user discards a scene session.
    // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
    // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
}


//MARK: - notification
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    self.userDeviceToken = deviceToken.hexString
    
    let userToken = KeychainModel.shared.retrieveString(key: .userDeviceToken) ?? ""
    let userID = KeychainModel.shared.retrieveString(key: .userID) ?? ""
    
    Messaging.messaging().token { stringToken, error in
        print("Firebase Token: \(stringToken)")
    }
    
    KeychainModel.shared.saveString(value: self.userDeviceToken, key: .userDeviceToken)
    print("self.userDeviceToken: \(self.userDeviceToken), userTokenKeychain: \(userToken)")
    // if have new device token need to update the deviceToken at "userModel"
    if self.userDeviceToken != userToken && userID != "" {
        let updateSet: [String: String] = [FirestoreModel.userParams.deviceToken.rawValue : self.userDeviceToken]
        FirestoreModel.shared.generalUpdate(collectionName: .users, documentName: userID, updateValue: updateSet) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("ERROR update token device: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("update token device successed")
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: \(error) ")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    let data = userInfo["user"] as? String        
    print("GET NOTIFICATION, userID: \(data)")
}
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to show all lines of codes in AppDelegate.

Comment: Added my AppDelegate page

Comment: I think that's because you don't have `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`  But who knows!?

Comment: Added that func, still not called at background...

Comment: I'm not going to join your wild goose chase.  You may want to list all the steps you have taken if you need more assistance.